# What situations trigger the Master Sword's special power?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

The master sword glows and does double damage in certain situations, but I'm not clear on what situations trigger it - it sounded like anything "calamity-related," but I'm not clear on what that means

It definitely glows when I face full-size guardians, but I'm not sure what else triggers it? Does it work against the calamity infested dragons, like the one on the icy mountain?

And does it need an enemy to activate it, or will the presence of "calamity goop" make it glow if you're fighting "normal" enemies nearby?

Comment: Side note: In addition to doing double damage, the Master's Sword's durability also increases by quite a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I know the following situations activate it:

- Being anywhere inside Hyrule Castle or a Divine Beast
- Fighting any of the full-size guardians (fighting the smaller scouts inside shrines will *not* activate it)

I know that "calamity goop" does *not* activate it.

Comment: I did not know that about being in Hyrule Castle.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Zelda Wiki page on the [Master Sword](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Master_Sword#Breath_of_the_Wild), the Master Sword should glow under a number of circumstances (emphasis mine):

> The Master Sword has a base strength of 30 damage; however, **its holy power is awakened in the presence of evil. While Link is inside a Dungeon or near Guardians or Malice, the blade glows with a blue aura**. In this state, the Master Sword's power is doubled to 60.

Thus, the Master Sword will enter its awoken state when:

- When Link is inside a [Dungeon](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Dungeon#Breath_of_the_Wild) (any Divine Beast or Hyrule Castle)
- When fighting full-sized [Guardians](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Guardian_(Breath_of_the_Wild))
- When fighting certain enemies affected by Calamity Ganon's [Malice](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Malice) (as Mage XY pointed out in the comments, certain enemies who are technically affected by Malice may not awaken the Master Sword eg Silver [Lynels](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Lynel#Breath_of_the_Wild))

There are also certain effects on the Master Sword's durability and abilities when awakened, but this information can be found in greater detail in the [Master Sword wiki entry](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Master_Sword#Breath_of_the_Wild).

Comment: The Master Sword does *not* get powered up when near Malice.

Comment: Interesting, I'm mainly going off the wiki. I can verify this when I get home later, though if someone else can confirm Malice does not awaken the Master Sword I'll remove it from the answer.

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say that it awakens when fighting enemies affected by Calamity Ganon's malice? @MageXy

Comment: Lore-wise, that's correct... but it doesn't always apply. Silver Lynels, for example, are stated in the Hyrule Compendium as having been corrupted by Ganon's magic... yet the Master Sword gets no bonus against them.

Comment: I see, I'll change my answer to reflect this more accurately